# Get status text after failed http-request

Tags: python, rest, httprequest, python-requests, raspbian

Is there any chance to get additional status information from my respose object, if a request fails? At this point, I'm able to get the status code, but in addition, I need the status information text (which describes the error). If you're using jQuery ajax, you could get this text from jqXHR's responseText-attribute.

Is there an equivalent for a python-requests response?

```
rsp = requests.put(url='{0}recorditems/{1}'
                    .format(Utils.configuration['service']['baseURI']
                            , recorditemOID)
                    , data=body
                    , headers=headers
                    , cert=Utils.configuration['daemon']['certFile']
                    , verify=True)

if rsp.status_code == 200:
    Utils.log('Erfassung {0} synchronisiert'.format(recorditemOID))
    return True
else:
    Utils.log('Status-Code -> {0}'.format(rsp.status_code))
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `Response.reason` attribute:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/')
print(r.reason)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResponseHandler` class with the `return_status()` function

```py
response = requests.get('http://www.google.com/')
ResponseHandler(response).return_status()
```